# Why is vim giving me an "i <Up> * <Esc><Up>" startup error with the mapping "inoremap <Up> <Esc><Up>"?

Tags: vimrc, error

Here is are the startup errors when I run vim:

```
i  <Up>        * <Esc><Up>
i  <Down>      * <Esc><Down>
i  <Left>      * <Esc><Left>
i  <Right>     * <Esc><Right>
i  <Home>      * <Esc>y
i  <End>       * <Esc>l
i  <PageUp>    * <Esc><PageUp>
i  <PageDown>  * <Esc><PageDown>
i  <kEnter>    * <Esc>o
```

Which result from these mappings:

```
inoremap <kEnter> <Esc>o 
inoremap <PageDown> <Esc><PageDown> 
inoremap <PageUp> <Esc><PageUp> 
inoremap <End> <Esc>l 
inoremap <Home> <Esc>y 
inoremap <Right> <Esc><Right> 
inoremap <Left> <Esc><Left> 
inoremap <Down> <Esc><Down> 
inoremap <Up> <Esc><Up>
```

I can't figure out what this is trying to tell me, because these bindings appear to work for me.

Comment: Those aren't errors. What you see is the output of a stray `:imap` command.

Comment: A stray :imap command? Do I need to show my entire .vimrc, or can you tell which command it is from looking at this snippet?

Comment: Yes, show us your `vimrc`.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17200916/

Comment: One of your plugins with a command like `:au BufEnter *.* :imap ` may cause this output to be shown everytime. When you open a file.

Comment: @Akiva line 220 in that paste is your problem.  Like romainl said, it's a stray `:imap` command.  Using `:i[nore]map` without any arguments prints all of the insert maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I had a stray

`i[nore]map`  [Line 220](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17200916/)

command, which by itself will print all insert maps. Removing this fixed my problem.